# Tensorflow data.Dataset.map and memory storage

Tags: tensorflow

I have a dataset of images that is too large to store on memory. What I plan to do is loading pairs of the paths to the images and corresponding labels as my dataset, then use a generator function during training to convert only the paths in my batch to images before feeding them to the network.

Is data.Dataset.map() a good way to do this? Does it return a mapping function, that can be applied only to the current batch during training, or does it perform the mapping operation on the whole dataset at once, occupying lots of memory? In the second case, what is an alternative?

A few tutorials I went through made me believe the mapping takes place per batch, but this quote from the documentation suggests a whole new dataset is returned: *"This transformation applies **map_func** to each element of this dataset, and returns a new dataset containing the transformed elements, in the same order as they appeared in the input."*

Comment: This (https://keras.io/examples/vision/keypoint_detection/) keras tutorial uses a similar dateset system, with the get_dog function retriving an image from path with a dictionary of paths.

Comment: You can use this method to create image data set https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

Comment: @35308 I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: @Ameya I chose to use paths+label for ease of applying k-fold crossvalidation and recording which images were used for validation on each fold. The labels on *tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory* must follow the order of the images on the directory, so I don't think k-fold would work without moving files around.

Comment: Any feedback on what the output of Dataset.map() is and how it is stored on memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to understand here is that `tf.data.Dataset` objects are generally "lazy" in that elements are only processed as needed (in a batched Dataset, elements == batches). When iterating over a dataset, this usually means that only the next requested element is prepared and then returned. So to answer your question: When using `map` to load data from disk, and applying this to a dataset of file names, only one batch of the loaded data should be stored in memory at the same time, and you should be able to process the dataset just fine. However, this can *significantly* slow down training if loading the files is a bottleneck in terms of speed.

There are some exceptions though, for example:

- When you use the `shuffle` method, you need to provide a buffer size, and AFAIK the entire buffer is preprocessed at once. This can lead to issues since you want a large buffer for good shuffling, but this requires more memory. Thus you probably want to use `shuffle` *before* applying `map`.
- The `prefetch` method results in multiple elements being prepared in order to avoid the model having to wait for the next batch to be processed.

Note that this lazy behavior also has some disadvantages, e.g.

- You can only iterate over datasets sequentially; there is no random access.
- A dataset doesn't even know how many elements it contains (this would require iterating over the entire set).

Comment: Great answer! Regarding datasets not knowing their size, what does it mean for the ```cardinality``` method? Is it actually iterating over the whole dataset and performing any mapping calculations for all entries?

Comment: That is a good point. I believe this is a (relatively) new feature, though I don't know when it was introduced. I suppose the length of certain datasets can be easily computed (e.g. for `from_tensor_slices`) and changes via some methods can be easily tracked (e.g. `batch` changes length in a predictable way, `map` doesn't change it etc.). I would assume these lengths are stored as constants somewhere. Unfortunately, the source code for this is very hard to understand.